# Is it possible to remove devices of others from the list shown in my Bluetooth settings?

Tags: bluetooth

In Windows Phone 8.1, I can go to Settings, and then Bluetooth.
When Bluetooth is turned on, it shows all the devices around me.

This is nice, but not for the phones and televisions of other people.
I don't plan to ever connect to any of their devices.

I would like to be able to remove or hide some of these specific devices.
Is this possible?

Comment: The other phones and devices don't get annoyed by being browsed, so I don't understand the problem?

Comment: It would be great to be able to hide unwanted nearby devices, and have an option to show hidden devices if they ever became needed.  This would make it easier to find the wanted devices in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then the answer is no, you cannot. Doing so wouldn't really make sense, since it would make you unable to connect to any devices you removed. It would be like deleting a Wi-Fi network from the list of available networks.

Comment: I agree that it might not make sense to remove a Bluetooth device from the list of connections available, but what about just hiding it somehow?

Comment: No, can't do it. I see how it would be convenient, but from Microsoft's viewpoint it would cause more headaches than it's worth.